# javascript revealing module pattern and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns

I'm trying to up my js foo and start to use the module patter more but I'm struggling.

I have a main page with a jquery-ui element that pops up a dialog that loads an ajax requested page for data entry.  The below code is contained within the popup ajax page.

After the pop up is loaded the Chrome console is able to see and execute `ProtoSCRD.testing()` just fine.  If I try to run that in the jQuery.ready block on the page, I get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ProtoSCRD is not defined

Yet i can execute  `toggleTypeVisable()` in the ready block and life is good.  Can anyone shed some light?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setHoodStyleState();
    $('#hood-style').change(function(){

        hstyle = $('#hood-style').val();
        if ( hstyle.indexOf('Custom') != -1) {
            alert('Custom hood style requires an upload drawing for clarity.');
        }
        setHoodStyleState();
    });

    setCapsState();
    $('#caps').change(function(){
        setCapsState();
    });

    setCustomReturnVisibility();
    $('#return').change(function(){ setCustomReturnVisibility(); });

    toggleTypeVisable();
    $('#rd_type').change(function(){
        toggleTypeVisable();
    });

    ProtoSCRD.testing();
});


function toggleTypeVisable(){

    if ( $('#rd_type').val() == 'Bracket' ) {
        $('.endcap-ctl').hide();
        $('.bracket-ctl').show();
    }
    if ( $('#rd_type').val() == 'Endcap' ) {
        $('.bracket-ctl').hide();
        $('.endcap-ctl').show();
    }

    if ( $('#rd_type').val() == 'Select One' ) {
        $('.bracket-ctl').hide();
        $('.endcap-ctl').hide();
    }
}



ProtoSCRD = (function($, w, undefined) {
    testing = function(){
        alert('testing');
        return '';
    }

    getDom = function(){
        return  $('#prd-order-lines-cnt');
    }

    return {
        testing: testing,
        getDom: getDom
    };
}(jQuery, window));
```

calling the popup dialog like so - which is in fact in another ready in a diff file on the parent page:

```
// enable prototype button
$( "#proto-btn" ).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    showPrototype();
});
```

Comment: Is this code within another jQuery.ready closure?

Comment: You're right, that doesn't make sense. That means the property is being removed/set equal to undefined between it being defined and the dom being ready. Where is your dom ready code in relation to this code?

Comment: I've added the doc ready statement.  it is the first code block right after the opening script tag.  Its not within another doc ready that I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it will solve your problems at all, but you are definitely missing several `var` statements you really should have:

```
var ProtoSCRD = (function($, w, undefined) {
    var testing = function(){
        alert('testing');
        return '';
    };

    var getDom = function(){
        return  $('#prd-order-lines-cnt');
    };

    return {
        testing: testing,
        getDom: getDom
    };
}(jQuery, window));
```

IMHO, it's best practice to use `var` for every variable you declare.  (Function declarations do so implicitly.)

But I really don't know if this will help solve anything.  But it should store everything in its proper scope.

### Update

Here's one possible issue:  if the document is already ready (say this is loading at the end of the body), then perhaps jQuery is running this synchronously.  Have you tried moving the definition of `ProtoSCRD` above the `document.ready` block?

Comment: Good call.  Flagged correct.  I've not had that issue when using jquery before.  You clued me into the ajax request that was calling the dialog.  While the ajax call is not set to use sync it is set to modular.  Wondering why I specifically had to have the order correct in this context.

Comment: @user290781: I don't know for sure, but I don't think it had to do with an ajax call at all.  If this code is running after the document is ready, then I believe jQuery's `document.ready` runs its callback function right away, so you hadn't yet defined your `ProtoSCRD` function, which is not defined until later.  (If you're used to using function declarations [`function foo() {...}`], you may be used to slightly different behavior, but this is how function expressions [`var foo = function() {...};` or even `var foo = (function() {...; return {...};}());`] work.)

Comment: It just clicked.  Ty for the clarity.